# Superuser didn't work

Tags: django, authentication, admin, root, django-syncdb

I want to create a super user to log into the admin panel, I use to do this command:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I do not use `./manage.py syncdb` (I use the South).

After creating a super user, I go to the address `/admin/` and enter the data you gave when creating a super user and get an error if I typed bad data.

Comment: What's the output of `python manage.py validate` ?

Comment: @fasouto 0 errors found

Comment: Ok. Are you using the default django authentication system or some package like Userena?